# How to stop infinity call using "+= (o, e) =>" in c#

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I am using GetFocus function of TabItem. I have differnt TabItems and when i switch between others then it must popup a MessageBox. I use the code below to do so:

```
       TabItem tbi = new TabItem();
       tbi.GotFocus += (o, e) => 
         {
          MessageBox.Show("it pop ups infinitely");
       };
```

How to make solution of it. Is it possible that it popup once and then control come out of this function ? I mean something like. "-=(o,e)" below the MessagebOX POP UP. (I guess it pop up infinitely because as i open the TabItem it persists open and it keep on poping up). (Please do not suggest LostFocus instead)

Comment: Well, an alert will take focus away from the tab item and when you dismiss it, it will return focus to the tab triggering the event again. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: @MattBurland Am i right for the reason of infinite call ?  @(I guess it pop up infinitely because as i open the TabItem it persists open and it keep on poping up).

Comment: No - I've just explained why it keeps popping up. You are triggering the event again every time you dismiss the alert. I don't know what you mean by "it persists open".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes sense this happens, because the MessageBox gets focus, and when you close it, the TabItem gets focus again. Maybe a simple boolean flag could fix it?

```
   bool focusing = false;
   TabItem tbi = new TabItem();
   tbi.GotFocus += (o, e) =>
   {
      if (focusing) {
          focusing = false;
          return;
      }
      focusing = true;
      MessageBox.Show("it pop ups infinitely");
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to remove the handler as soon as it is first called?

```
RoutedEventHandler handler = null;
handler = (o, e) => 
       {
          MessageBox.Show("it pop ups infinitely");
          tbi.GotFocus -= handler;
       };

tbi.GotFocus += handler;
```